# Combined frequency histogram using two attributes

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I'm using ggplot2 to create histograms for two different parameters. My current approach is attached at the end of my question (including a dataset, which can be used and loaded right from pasetbin.com), which creates

1. a histrogram visualizing the frequency for the spatial distribution of logged user data based on the "location"-attribute (either "WITHIN" or "NOT_WITHIN").
2. a histogram visualizing the frequency for the distribution of logged user data based on the "context"-attribute (either "Clicked A" or "Clicked B").

This looks like the follwoing:
[image]

```
# Load my example dataset from pastebin
RawDataSet <- read.csv("http://pastebin.com/raw/uKybDy03", sep=";")
# Load packages
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)

###### Create Frequency Table for Location-Information
LocationFrequency <- ddply(RawDataSet, .(UserEmail), summarize, 
                           All = length(UserEmail),
                           Within_area = sum(location=="WITHIN"),
                           Not_within_area = sum(location=="NOT_WITHIN"))
# Create a column for unique identifiers
LocationFrequency <- mutate(LocationFrequency, id = rownames(LocationFrequency))
# Reorder columns
LocationFrequency <- LocationFrequency[,c(5,1:4)]
# Format id-column as numbers (not as string)
LocationFrequency[,c(1)] <- sapply(LocationFrequency[, c(1)], as.numeric)
# Melt data
LocationFrequency.m = melt(LocationFrequency, id.var=c("UserEmail","All","id"))
# Plot data
p <- ggplot(LocationFrequency.m, aes(x=id, y=value, fill=variable)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  theme_grey(base_size = 16)+
  labs(title="Histogram showing the distribution of all spatial information per user.") + 
  labs(x="User", y="Number of notifications interaction within/not within the area") +
  # using IDs instead of UserEmail
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30), labels=c("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23","24","25","26","27","28","29","30"))
# Change legend Title
p + labs(fill = "Type of location")



##### Create Frequency Table for Interaction-Information
InterationFrequency <- ddply(RawDataSet, .(UserEmail), summarize, 
                             All = length(UserEmail),
                             Clicked_A = sum(context=="Clicked A"),
                             Clicked_B = sum(context=="Clicked B"))
# Create a column for unique identifiers
InterationFrequency <- mutate(InterationFrequency, id = rownames(InterationFrequency))
# Reorder columns
InterationFrequency <- InterationFrequency[,c(5,1:4)]
# Format id-column as numbers (not as string)
InterationFrequency[,c(1)] <- sapply(InterationFrequency[, c(1)], as.numeric)
# Melt data
InterationFrequency.m = melt(InterationFrequency, id.var=c("UserEmail","All","id"))
# Plot data
p <- ggplot(InterationFrequency.m, aes(x=id, y=value, fill=variable)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  theme_grey(base_size = 16)+
  labs(title="Histogram showing the distribution of all interaction types per user.") + 
  labs(x="User", y="Number of interaction") +
  # using IDs instead of UserEmail 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30), labels=c("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23","24","25","26","27","28","29","30"))
  # Change legend Title
  p + labs(fill = "Type of interaction")
```

---

But what I'm trying to realize: How can I combine both histograms in only one plot? Would it be somehow possible to place the corressponding percentage for each part? Somethink like the following sketch, which represents the total number of observations per user (the complete height of the bar) and using the different segmentation to visualize the corresponding data. Each bar would be divided into to parts (*within* and *not_within*) where each part would be then divided into two subparts showing the percentage of the interaction types (*Clicked A' or *Clicked B*).

[image: sketch]

Comment: Can you please incorporate the data into your post? Relying on an outside source to persist is naive at best. Simulate data or use one of the existing datasets already shipped with R or one of the (common) packages.

Comment: A histogram, by definition, can only show one variable (unless you put text labels on it, perhaps). Are you looking for a mosaic plot?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik: Sorry. I've thought that the included pastebin-link is the perfect solution to make the question as manageable as possible as you're easily able to consume my data using the provided link. Anyway...I will include a snippet of my dataset shortly.

Comment: @alistaire: Interesting information ;) I've searched for "mosaic plots" and this could do the trick, although I would have no idea how to visualize the different frequencies.

Comment: @Jaap Thanks for your answer. I've updated my question and commented your answer. Maybe you'll find some time to have a look on my respond and/or edits of my question :)?

Comment: See the updated answer. I've added several customizations as well. HTH

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the update description, I would make a combined barplot with two parts: a negative and a positve one. In order to achieve that, you have to get your data into the correct format:

```
# load needed libraries
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

# summarise your data
new.df <- RawDataSet %>% 
  group_by(UserEmail,location,context) %>% 
  tally() %>%
  mutate(n2 = n * c(1,-1)[(location=="NOT_WITHIN")+1L]) %>%
  group_by(UserEmail,location) %>%
  mutate(p = c(1,-1)[(location=="NOT_WITHIN")+1L] * n/sum(n))
```

The `new.df` dataframe looks like:

```
> new.df
Source: local data frame [90 x 6]
Groups: UserEmail, location [54]

   UserEmail   location   context     n    n2          p
      (fctr)     (fctr)    (fctr) (int) (dbl)      (dbl)
1      andre NOT_WITHIN Clicked A     3    -3 -1.0000000
2       bibi NOT_WITHIN Clicked A     4    -4 -0.5000000
3       bibi NOT_WITHIN Clicked B     4    -4 -0.5000000
4       bibi     WITHIN Clicked A     9     9  0.6000000
5       bibi     WITHIN Clicked B     6     6  0.4000000
6     corinn NOT_WITHIN Clicked A    10   -10 -0.5882353
7     corinn NOT_WITHIN Clicked B     7    -7 -0.4117647
8     corinn     WITHIN Clicked A     9     9  0.7500000
9     corinn     WITHIN Clicked B     3     3  0.2500000
10  dpfeifer NOT_WITHIN Clicked A     7    -7 -1.0000000
..       ...        ...       ...   ...   ...        ...
```

Next you can create a plot with:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_bar(data = new.df[new.df$location == "NOT_WITHIN",],
           aes(x = UserEmail, y = n2, color = "darkgreen", fill = context),
           size = 1, stat = "identity", width = 0.7) +
  geom_bar(data = new.df[new.df$location == "WITHIN",],
           aes(x = UserEmail, y = n2, color = "darkred", fill = context),
           size = 1, stat = "identity", width = 0.7) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(-20,20,5),
                     labels = c(20,15,10,5,0,5,10,15,20)) +
  scale_color_manual("Location of interaction",
                     values = c("darkgreen","darkred"),
                     labels = c("NOT_WITHIN","WITHIN")) +
  scale_fill_manual("Type of interaction",
                    values = c("lightyellow","lightblue"),
                    labels = c("Clicked A","Clicked B")) +
  guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(color = c("darkred","darkgreen"),
                                                  fill = NA, size = 2), reverse = TRUE),
         fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(fill = c("lightyellow","lightblue"),
                                                 color = "black", size = 0.5))) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust = 0.5, size = 14),
        axis.title = element_blank(),
        legend.title = element_text(face = "italic", size = 14),
        legend.key.size = unit(1, "lines"),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 11))
```

which results in:

[image]

If you want to use percentage values, you can use the `p`-column to make a plot:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_bar(data = new.df[new.df$location == "NOT_WITHIN",],
           aes(x = UserEmail, y = p, color = "darkgreen", fill = context),
           size = 1, stat = "identity", width = 0.7) +
  geom_bar(data = new.df[new.df$location == "WITHIN",],
           aes(x = UserEmail, y = p, color = "darkred", fill = context),
           size = 1, stat = "identity", width = 0.7) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(-1,-0.75,-0.5,-0.25,0,0.25,0.5,0.75,1),
                     labels = scales::percent(c(1,0.75,0.5,0.25,0,0.25,0.5,0.75,1))) +
  scale_color_manual("Location of interaction",
                     values = c("darkgreen","darkred"),
                     labels = c("NOT_WITHIN","WITHIN")) +
  scale_fill_manual("Type of interaction",
                    values = c("lightyellow","lightblue"),
                    labels = c("Clicked A","Clicked B")) +
  coord_flip() +
  guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(color = c("darkred","darkgreen"),
                                                  fill = NA, size = 2), reverse = TRUE),
         fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(fill = c("lightyellow","lightblue"),
                                                 color = "black", size = 0.5))) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 14) +
  theme(axis.title = element_blank(),
        legend.title = element_text(face = "italic", size = 14),
        legend.key.size = unit(1, "lines"),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 11))
```

which results in:

[image]

---

***In response to the comment***

If you want to place the text-labels inside the bars, you will have to calculate a position variable too:

```
new.df <- RawDataSet %>% 
  group_by(UserEmail,location,context) %>% 
  tally() %>%
  mutate(n2 = n * c(1,-1)[(location=="NOT_WITHIN")+1L]) %>%
  group_by(UserEmail,location) %>%
  mutate(p = c(1,-1)[(location=="NOT_WITHIN")+1L] * n/sum(n),
         pos = (context=="Clicked A")*p/2 + (context=="Clicked B")*(c(1,-1)[(location=="NOT_WITHIN")+1L] * (1 - abs(p)/2)))
```

Then add the following line to your `ggplot` code after the `geom_bar`'s:

```
geom_text(data = new.df, aes(x = UserEmail, y = pos, label = n))
```

which results in:

[image]

Instead of `label = n` you can also use `label = scales::percent(abs(p))` to display the percentages.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was not aware that my data is actually so complex that I would not be able to plot the two different attributes into one plot. Thanks for the clarrification. The plot provided in your answer is quite useful, although it is not exactly what I was looking for. I've updated my question including a sketch how a bar should be visualized. 
...Nevertheless: If my "aimed plot" is not possible: Is it somehow possible to place the percentage for each of the four values next to the bar-parts?

Comment: This is awesome :) Just one short question: Running the code for the second plot gives me a warning message: _Warning message:
Stacking not well defined when ymin != 0_, which results in the error that the percentage values are not displayed correctly and that the bars are not alligned. The output looks like the following: http://i.imgur.com/qy7MTOi.png Do you know what is causing the problem?

Comment: @schlomm Spent quite some time tinkering with it ;-). With regard to the warning: I get the same warning, but that is as expected as the code forces to plot stacked bars below `0`. Which version of `ggplot2` are you using (I'm using R3.2.3 & ggplot 2 2.0.0)?

Comment: It's working :) Checking my ggplot version was a very helpful link. Can I ask one very last question? I've tried to place the corresponding percentage-value of each bar-part into the plot using `geom_text(data = new.df, aes(x = UserEmail, y = p, label = n), size = 4)`. However and as you might notice, I was only able to place the number of observations into the bars; not the percentage. Is this easily to achieve?