# How to add legend to ggplot multiple geom_bar

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a code like this

```
# two data frames
sf =  data.frame(days = c('05-06', '05,08'), Frequency = c(0, 2))
normal = data.frame(days = c('05-06', '05,07'), Frequency = c(1, 3))

# plot
ggplot() + 
  geom_bar(aes(y = Frequency, x = days), data = normal, 
           stat="identity", colour = 'black') +
  geom_bar(aes(y = Frequency, x = days), data = sf, 
           stat="identity", colour = 'red')
```

I want to add legend to it with red and black color, I tried this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13789458/combined-line-bar-geoms-how-to-generate-proper-legend) which is the most related solution to my question, but it just shows the legend for the first barplot. How can I have a barplot legend with black and red color?

Notice: it is not one data frame, they are two separate data frames, with different number of rows, so I can not merge them together. So I plot two bar plots. The above code fill the plots, what I want is to add a legend that shows the first bar plot is black and the second one is red.

Comment: please provide reproducible example.

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible code example (most importantly a dataset)? I'm not 100% sure what you are trying to achieve. Do you want a red legend with a black border?

Comment: No I just want to have a legend, that shows a red box and a label for the first bar and another black box for the second bar.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change bar plot colour in geom\_bar with ggplot2 in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38788357/change-bar-plot-colour-in-geom-bar-with-ggplot2-in-r)

Comment: No it is not a duplicate, here we have two geom_bar!

Comment: I still don't truly see what you are trying to do from the code. You may want to add a annotated photo of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: But I still don't think you need to have to separate geoms. You should ideally have the data in a single datagrams, and then have a column for each observation of `sf/normal`. This column can then be passed to the `aes(col =colname) ` within the geom_barplot. You can then refer to my duplicate post on how to change the colour

Comment: See if my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46821590/8449629) works for you? Use `scale_fill_manual` & define the fill inside each `geom_bar()`'s aesthetic mapping.

Comment: Why do you need two gems and what `05,07` means?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35255234/combined-frequency-histogram-using-two-attributes

Answer (score 2):

As with many ggplot questions, the problem you are facing stems from the data not being in the correct format. You should have a single dataframe, with the columns `days`, `Frequency` and `group`.

Set the colour within the aesthetic group of the ggplot, and then specify an manual colour scale to set the colours and black.

```
library(ggplot2)

df =  data.frame(days = c('05-06', '05,08', '05-06', '05,07'),
                 Frequency = c(0, 2, 1, 3),
                 group = c("sf", "sf", "normal", "normal"))


# plot
ggplot(df, aes(y = Frequency, x = days, fill = group)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "black"))
```

[image]

> I would encourage reading the basics of ggplot reference guidance to get a bit more of an understanding about how to use the data: http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/. In addition, the ggplot cheatsheet is a useful reference: https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/ggplot2-cheatsheet.pdf